# Calling a generic lambda in boost::mpl::for_each()

Tags: c++, templates, boost, lambda, boost-mpl

A few answers here ([How to loop through a boost::mpl::list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840640/how-to-loop-through-a-boostmpllist) being the one I started with) imply that I should be able to construct a generic lambda to feed to a boost::mpl::for_each() but I'm unable to find a working example, or build one myself.

Idealy what I would like to be able to do in a lambda is take a function like

```
template<typename T>
void TestFunction(const int &p)
{
  T t(p);
  std::cout << "p = " << p << ", t = " << t << std::endl;
};
```

that I'm currently calling in a loop with something like

```
for(int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
{
  TestFunction<int>(k);
  TestFunction<long>(k);
  TestFunction<float>(k);
  TestFunction<double>(k);
};
```

and replace it with something like

```
typedef boost::mpl::list<int, long, float, double> ValidTypes;

for(int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
{
  // lambda definition that captures k

  // boost::mpl::for_each(ValidTypes, ...) that calls the lambda.
};
```

Is this possible? If not with for_each() with one of the other mpl constructs? I've got a version of the code running where I overload operator() but I'd like to see a lambda solution if it's possible.

Thanks,
    Andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use C++14's generalized lambdas, you can capture the value of `p` and also infer the type of the current valid type being passed to the lambda:

```
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    using ValidTypes = boost::mpl::list<int, long, float, double>;

    for (auto k = 0; k < 2; ++k) {
        boost::mpl::for_each<ValidTypes>([p = k](auto arg) { 
            using T = decltype(arg);
            T t(p);
            std::cout << "p = " << p << ", t = " << t << '\n'; 
        });
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A7F6N2Fph8nxI7CP).

**Edit**: for extra credit, here's a slightly more advanced version that also works for non-default constructible types:

```
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class NonDefaultConstructible
{
    int value;
public:
    NonDefaultConstructible(int const& p) : value(p) {}

    friend auto& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, NonDefaultConstructible const& ndc)
    {
        return ostr << ndc.value;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    using ValidTypes = boost::mpl::list<int, long, float, double, NonDefaultConstructible>;

    for (auto k = 0; k < 2; ++k) {
        boost::mpl::for_each<ValidTypes, boost::mpl::make_identity<boost::mpl::_1>>([p = k](auto arg) { 
            using T = typename decltype(arg)::type;
            T t(p);
            std::cout << "p = " << p << ", t = " << t << '\n'; 
        });
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3sHtz67BKaoRt75M).

For an explanation of the somewhat convoluted use of `make_identity`, see my [**very first Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574378/type-wrapper-error-with-boostmplfor-each-section-9-1-1-from-abrahams-gurt) here!

Comment: Thank you @TemplateRex! The make_identity<> trick was the missing link from my attempts!!!